# How to Render a Video as an .mp4 Format?

Tags: rendering, export

Yes, I've read other topics asking the same question, and changed all the output settings that I know someone will reply with. Keep in mind, I'm very new to using Blender as a video editor. However, when I render or save the video, it saves as a .png or a .blend. My settings are changed to:
File Format: FFmpeg,
Container: mp4,
Codec: mp4.
Where exactly do I go to render/save it as an mp4?

Comment: It is a best practice to render to image sequence first and then render the sequence to video. That way, if something happens midway through render you can continue at that point with no lost data. With video render you lose everything and start over.

Comment: If you do want to render straight to video, from the Render menu select Render Animation or use CTRL F12.